# Split JWT into two cookies

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have been researching about JWT to implement a better practice way for more secure against XSS & CSRF attacks.(I am so confused during the research so feel free to correct me) So basically this is what I found;

- Split JWT into two cookies.
- Save header + signature with httpOnly,secure & sameSite flags
- Save payload with httpOnly flag false

I am pretty new to the development environment so, to be honest, I am stuck at this point. Is the idea I am trying to achieve is accurate? Is this the right way? Is this secure that I send both on the same page?

this is my code below,

-Helpers/Authorization/jwtHelpers.js

```
module.exports = {

    sendJwtToClient: (user,res)=>{

        let token = user.generateJWT();

        const [header,payload,signature] = token.split(".");

        const {JWT_COOKIE,NODE_ENV} = process.env;

   //Signature & Header cookie should have httpOnly flag = true
        res.status(200).cookie("access_token",header+signature,{
            httpOnly:true,
            sameSite:true,
            secure:true,
        
    //Payload cookie should have httpOnly flag = false
        }).cookie("access",payload,{
            httpOnly:false,
            secure:true,
            sameSite:true,
            expires:new Date(Date.now()+parseInt(JWT_COOKIE) + 1000 * 60),
        }).json({
            success:true
        })

    }
}
```

/Models/User.js

```
schema.methods.generateJWT = function () {
    const { JWT_SECRET } = process.env;

    const payload = {
        _id: this._id,
        email: this.email
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(payload, JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "30m"
    })

    return token;
}
```

As I said before, please feel free to correct or direct me because I am so confused.

Comment: I don't see the point in doing this.  JWT are, in theory, tamper-proof, because the server can easily detect whether an incoming JWT from the outside has been tampered with.  But, a JWT is still visible/readable to anybody.  If the latter be a concern, then you should encrypt the JWT as well.  Splitting into 2 separate cookies strikes me as a lot of work for not much benefit.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. What do you suggest? Can you direct me with any link or post about that topic so I can read?

Comment: For the first part of my comment, you need not "do" anything, the JWT pattern already provides this protection.  For the second part, just Google for "encrypt JWT" to get some ideas on how to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the idea behind splitting the jwt into two cookies is that the client still has access to the data (via the non-httpOnly cookie), but the full jwt cannot be stolen via xss (as easily) because client cannot access the signature via js (because it's in an httpOnly cookie).